# ¿Cómo acceder a los archivos enviados con fetch desde php?

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

Lo que quiero hacer es enviar una solicitud con fetch que contiene en su body un objeto File y desde PHP acceder al File y devolverlo. Lo que tengo es esto:

En JavaScript:

```
const archivo = new File(["foo"], "foo.txt");
       fetch("php.php", {method:"POST", body:archivo})
           .then((response) => response.text())
           .then((text)=>{
           console.log(text);
       })
   }
```

En php:

```
<?php
  echo $_POST["body"];
?>
```

Supongo que falla porque $_POST["body"] no accede al archivo que he puesto en el body del fetch. ¿Cómo puedo acceder a el?

Intentando averiguarlo por internet no encontré mucha información porque la mayoria de datos del body del fetch eran objetos y tenian pares clave:valor o simplemente eran formData en los ejemplos que yo encontraba.

Quise averiguar que había en el $_POST del php para saber si había alguna clave para acceder a ese  archivo del body pero ocurrio esto:

```
<?php
  var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

De nuevo en JS:

```
const archivo = new File(["foo"], "foo.txt");
       fetch("php.php", {method:"POST", body:archivo})
           .then((response) => response.text())
           .then((text)=>{
           console.log(text);//array(0){ }
       })
   }
```

Entonces me surgió la duda de que si el archivo del body se estaba enviando junto a la solicitud. Al parecer no lo hace ¿porque? y como si lo hubiera hecho ¿cómo podría haber accedido a el?

Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no usas un formulario el contenido lo puedes obtener directamente del *flujo de entrada*  `php://input` especificando el tipo de contenido.

En este ejemplo se envía a PHP el archivo con texto `foo` y regresa la cadena modificada `foobar`:

```
<?php
   if( isset($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']) ){
      header( 'Content-Type: '.$_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] );
      $txt = file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
      $txt .= 'bar';
      echo $txt;
   }else{ 
?>
<script>
function enviar(){
   const archivo = new File( ["foo"], "foo.txt", {type: "text/plain"} )
   fetch( ''
        , { method: 'POST'
          , headers: { 'Content-Type': archivo.type }
          , body: archivo
          } 
        ).then( (res) => console.log( res.text() ) )
}
</script>
<button onclick="enviar()">Enviar</button>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Gracias era justo lo que quería! Aunque eso no es muy inseguro? Me refiero a que si puede presentar fallos de seguridad o que me puedan hackear usando eso?

Comment: En cuanto a seguridad, todo depende de lo que hagas después con el contenido, como en cualquier otro código.

Answer (score 4):

Te cuento algo

Para enviar archivos a través de **AJAX** con **Fetch** deberías enviar tus datos con un [FormaData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FormData) y el **header** `Content-Type` con el valor `multipart/form-data`

Como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```html
<input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile">
<button id="send">Enviar</button>
```

```js
// Obtenemos una referencia al input tipo file
const myFileElement = document.querySelector('#myFile');
// Obtenemos una referencia al botón de enviar
const sendBtn = document.querySelector('#send');
// Aqui guardaremos el archivo
let myFile = null;

// Obtenemos el file en cuanto te agregue uno nuevo al input
myFileElement.addEventListener('change', event => {
    myFile = event.target.files[0]
});

sendBtn.addEventListener('click', event => {
    // Prevenimos cualquier acción por defecto del boton
    event.preventDefault();

    // Creamos el FormData y le añadimos un campo
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('myFile', myFile);

    // Enviamos la solicitud AJAX de tipo POST
    fetch('php.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        body: formData
    })
    .then(res => {
        // Imprimimos la respuesta
        console.log(res.json())
    });
});
```

Y del lado del servidor con PHP hacemos lo siguiente:

```php
<?php
// Se establece el tipo de contenido de la respuesta
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// La variable global $_FILES contiene los archivos subidos
if (isset($_FILES) && count($_FILES) > 0 && isset($_FILES['myFile'])) {
    http_response_code(200);
    
    echo json_encode($_FILES['myFile']);
}
else {
    http_response_code(400);

    echo json_encode([
        'message' => 'Error, no se encontro ningun archivo'
    ]);
}
```

Ese sería un ejemplo algo completo de como sería el proceso, si quieres devolver el archivo completo, por ejemplo en formato `data-uri` el proceso es un poco distinto.

##### Respuesta extendida: ¿Como enviar archivos con por AJAX en formato json?

Como te decía en los comentarios el uso de un [FormaData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FormData) para enviar archivos al servidor funciona muy bien pero en caso de que necesites enviarlos en formato **json** hay una alternativa

Y es la siguiente:

```js
// Obtenemos una referencia al input tipo file
const myFileElement = document.querySelector('#myFile');
// Obtenemos una referencia al botón de enviar
const sendBtn = document.querySelector('#send');
// Aqui guardaremos el archivo
let myFile = null;
let base64 = null;

// Obtenemos el file en cuanto te agregue uno nuevo al input
myFileElement.addEventListener('change', event => {
    myFile = event.target.files[0]
});

sendBtn.addEventListener('click', event => {
    // Prevenimos cualquier acción por defecto del botón
    event.preventDefault();

    // Creamos un FileReader para obtener el Base64 del archivo
    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.addEventListener('load', () => {
        base64 = fileReader.result.replace(/^data:(.+)\/(.+);base64,/i, '');
    });

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(myFile);

    // Enviamos la solicitud AJAX de tipo POST
    fetch('php.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
             archivo: {
                 name: myFile.name,
                 type: myFile.type,
                 content: base64
             }
        })
    })
    .then(res => {
        // Imprimimos la respuesta
        console.log(res.json())
    });
});
```

Y en ese caso del lado de **PHP** haremos lo siguiente:

```php
<?php

// Se establece el tipo de contenido de la respuesta
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// Obtenemos los valores enviados a través de AJAX
$json_post = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true) ?? null;

// En este caso el archivo no estará en $_FILES sino en en la URL php://input
if (!is_null($json_post) && isset($json_post['archivo'])) {
    http_response_code(200);

    echo json_encode($json_post['archivo']);
}
else {
    http_response_code(400);

    echo json_encode([
        'message' => 'Error, no se encontro ningun archivo'
    ]);
}
```

La Clase de **Javascript** usada para leer obtener el base64 del archivo es [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader). Básicamente nos permite leer un `Blob` o `File` como **data-uri**, que es un formato de URL que trae el binario del archivo y su tipo incrustado en la URL y parseado a base64.

##### Nota extra: ¿Cómo hacer para almacenar el archivo en este caso?

Bien en ese caso solo haremos lo siguiente:

```php
<?php

// Obtenemos los valores enviados a través de AJAX
$json_post = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true) ?? null;

// En este caso el archivo no estará en $_FILES sino en en la URL php://input
if (!is_null($json_post) && isset($json_post['archivo'])) {
    // Creamos el archivo y obtenemos su resource
    $file = fopen($json_post['archivo']['name'], 'w+');
    
    // Parseamos a binario el base64
    $bin = base64_decode($json_post['archivo']['content']);
    
    // Escribimos el archivo
    fwrite($file, $bin);
   
    // Cerramos el archivo
    fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: No hay ninguna otra forma de haerlo sin usar FormData?

Comment: No veo porqué no usar `FormData`, pero sí, claro que hay una manera de enviarlo como **json** aunque más pesada en cuestiones de rendimiento, ya editó y la agrego a la respuesta

Comment: @Roberto listo amigo, ya agregue una nota bastante extendida jaja espero haber aclarado tus dudas

Comment: jaja, si que me aclaraste ^^, pero me acaba de surgir otra duda, viendo esto https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#body, dice que yo puedo enviar cualquier tipo de dato en ese formato, el problema y por eso pregunte antes, era que si yo enviaba datos en forma de FIle (o ArrayBuffer o Blob, ....), como accedo a través de PHP a ellos?